# Error: Error building ARM Config: Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a Service Principal)

Tags: azure, terraform

I am executing terraform init and I am receiving the next error. I want to create a Resource Group and storage the terraform.tfstate in a storage account:

To authenticate to Azure using a Service Principal, you can use the separate 'Authenticate using a Service Principal'│ auth method - instructions for which can be found here: [https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret│ │](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret%E2%94%82%C2%A0%E2%94%82) Alternatively you can authenticate using the Azure CLI by using a User Account.

This is my file main.tf

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "main" {}

output "main" {
  value = data.azurerm_subscription.main.display_name
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "TerraformGroup" {
  name = "TerraformTest1"
  location = "South Central US"
```

And my file versions.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.15.0"

  required_providers {
     azurerm    = ">= 3.46.0"
  }

  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "rg01"
    storage_account_name = "digital"
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }


}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {
  }
}
```

When I removed the backend it works but what I want is to store the terraform.state in a storage account

**Update**

according to @SiddheshDesai's answer use this main.tf to upload the terraform.tfstate to a storage account

```
terraform {  
required_providers {    
azurerm  =  {    
source = "hashicorp/azurerm"    
version = ">= 3.46.0"    
}  
}} 

provider  "azurerm" {
features {}
} 


terraform {  
backend  "azurerm" {  
resource_group_name  =  "<RG_NAME_STORAGE_ACCOUNT>"  
storage_account_name  =  "<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>"  
container_name  =  "CONTAINER_NAME"  
key  =  "terraform.tfstate"  
access_key = "<ACCESS_KEY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT>"  
}}
```

I just needed to create a service principal and run

> az login --service-principal -u <client_id> -p < secret > --tenant <tenant_id>

before the terraform commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to deploy the **Storage account** with **Service principal in Terraform**,
***You need to add your Service principal Client ID, Client secret, Subscription Id and Tenant Id as a terraform code.***

***Azure CLI is used for authenticating user name and password  by logging into your azure account with `az log in` and then the terraform uses the same account that you have logged in with Azure cli, But it does not work for Service principal authentication.***

*I used the below code to create a Storage account with Container and blob containing the tf state file using Service principal authentication.*

**Terraform code :-**

`main.tf`

```
  

terraform {

required_providers {

azurerm  =  {

source = "hashicorp/azurerm"

version = "3.8.0"

}

}

}

  

provider  "azurerm" {

subscription_id  =  "<subscription-id>"

tenant_id  =  "<tenant-id>"

client_id  =  "<client-id>"

client_secret  =  "<client-secret>"

features {}

}

  

resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "appgrp" {

name  =  "rg-name"

location  =  "North Europe"

}

  

resource  "azurerm_storage_account"  "siliconstrg0985" {

name  =  "siliconstrg0985"

resource_group_name  =  "app-grp"

location  =  "North Europe"

account_tier  =  "Standard"

account_replication_type  =  "LRS"

account_kind  =  "StorageV2"

depends_on  =  [

azurerm_resource_group.appgrp

]

}

  

resource  "azurerm_storage_container"  "data" {

name  =  "data"

storage_account_name  =  "siliconstrg0985"

container_access_type  =  "blob"

depends_on  =  [

azurerm_storage_account.siliconstrg0985

]

}

  

resource  "azurerm_storage_blob"  "maintf" {

name  =  "main.tf"

storage_account_name  =  "siliconstrg0985"

storage_container_name  =  "data"

type  =  "Block"

source  =  "main.tf"

depends_on  =  [

azurerm_storage_container.data

]

}

  

terraform {

backend  "azurerm" {

resource_group_name  =  "app-grp"

storage_account_name  =  "siliconstrg0985"

container_name  =  "data"

key  =  "terraform.tfstate"

}

}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Portal:-

[image]

Comment: To make it work I have to do an az login, the problem is that I want to run everything through a pipeline and I don't know if I have a service principal

Comment: You can create a service principal and its secret by following this document -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal > Using service principal is a recommended method for running and automating pipelines instead of az login

Comment: Since I already had a storage account created, I needed to put the access key of the storage account in the main.tf, with that it no longer asked me to log in with the az login command. thanks